# read line using select string until . character found

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am facing a problem on PowerShell reading line. My requirement is :

**using select string, if a pattern found, than read line until "." is found and show the output in one line.**

My file looks like that:

```
 file: this is the first 
 file for
 read.
 error:this is the error.
 data: this is the data.
 file: this is the 
 second file.
```

In the file, if "file" is found, than read the full line until next "." is found. Because the line is truncated.

Desired Output is:

```
file: this is the first file to read.
file: this is the second file.
//file name will be removed before
```

I try like:

```
 $totalFile = Select-String *.log -pattern "file:" -CaseSensitive -Context 0,1| % {$_.line}| Out-File "result.txt"
```

But context is not working because some file is in 2 line some are in 3 line. And also output is not showing in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `regex` to capture the desired output and use `-replace` to remove the new line characters:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'yourPath' -filter '*.log' | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw
    [regex]::Matches($content, "(file[^\.]+\.?)") | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Groups[0].Value -replace '\r?\n'
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
file: this is the first  file for read.
file: this is the  second file.
```

Comment: thanks for the help .... but i am not sure this works in version 2 .... as this showing an error ...

Comment: Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.  this is the error first line

Comment: Just omit the -raw parameter, it will still work. Also you should have mentioned that you are using Powershell-v2 ....

Comment: please just one more favor, if there exists two dot, than i want till the second dot like file: this is the first.  file for read.

Comment: replace the question mark in the regex with a star: `(file[^\.]+\.*)`

Comment: thanks but till to first dot ... not taking second dot.

Comment: you mean that after the dot will be more text (not just two dots)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124139/discussion-between-eric-ipsum-and-martin-brandl).